# Sending data via POST method from windows phone and handle the data via asp.net using POST method

Tags: asp.net, post

I want to send data from my Windows Phone 8.1 to my ASP.NET website via POST method. How can I handle the data in asp.net server via POST method from Windows Phone? Also after processing the data I want to store that data to a SQL server.

I already completed the sending data part using HttpWebRequest. I need help for processing the data in asp.net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your code  behind of that specific aspx page try  this

```
string name= Request.Form["name"];
string fname= Request.Form["fathername"];
```